# how to use styled-components library in angular 6 or up

Tags: angular6, styled-components, angular7

I want to use the styled-components library (https://www.styled-components.com/) in my angular project. But I cannot find any resources about how to use this library in angular 6 or up. So how can I use this library in my angular project

I have used this library in with react project. So will I able to use this library in an angular project like I use the library to react.

If not I like to know the way to use this styled-components library with angular 6 or up

Comment: Seems like Styled is specifically for React.  One of it's dependencies on npmjs.org is "css-to-react-native"... This person may have created something similar to styled  for angular - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-styled-components

Comment: Two years later i'm asking the same question - so far haven't found anything

Comment: I don't think it is neccessary beacuse in Angular all componets styles are encapsullated by default. Addtionally adding the css preprocessors (such us scss or less) you can achiave the same thing but in my opinion looks more brightful.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support Angular, I don't know why they don't explicitly announce this on their home page. For CSS-in-JS need, I just found an [article](https://dev.to/aziziyazit/css-in-js-for-angular-1no4) discussion on this topic.